# JMenuBar items Stuck under the Canvas of vlcj

Tags: java, user-interface, vlcj, jtoolbar

hello i am trying fix my JMenuBar issue as it showing in the picture posted in the question my JMenuBar item are not opening in right way which is over the Canvas not under the Canvas 
[image: java application frame]

the code for the application

```
    public class GuiInterface extends JFrame {
    Canvas c;
    private final JMenu jMenu1,jMenu2,jMenu3;
    private final JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private final JMenuItem itemNewSrt,itemOpenVideo,itemSavefile;
    JToolBar toolBar;    

        public GuiInterface(String title){

    //reader = new ReadFile();

    setSize(1024, 720);
    setVisible(true);
    setTitle("AnimeFactor");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(GuiInterface.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //video setting 
    MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
    c = new Canvas();
    String[] petStrings = { "Translation Line", "Both Line" };
    laList = new JComboBox(petStrings);
    c.setBackground(Color.black);
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(c, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(c));
    mediaPlayer.playMedia("C:\\Users\\isslam\\Downloads\\gg.mp4");
    table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0));
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
    TableColumn columnA = table.getColumn("#");
    columnA.setMinWidth(10);
    columnA.setMaxWidth(40);
    TableColumn columnB= table.getColumn("Start");
    columnB.setMinWidth(80);
    columnB.setMaxWidth(90);
    TableColumn columnC= table.getColumn("End");
    columnC.setMinWidth(80);
    columnC.setMaxWidth(90);


    ImageIcon openIcon = new ImageIcon(
                GuiInterface.class.getResource("/resources/image/folder-icon.png"));
        ImageIcon saveIcon = new ImageIcon(
                GuiInterface.class.getResource("/resources/image/red-disk-icon.png"));
        ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon(
                GuiInterface.class.getResource("/resources/image/Actionsnew-icon.png"));




        Action openAction = new AbstractAction("Open Subtitle", openIcon) {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ourFileSelector.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
                ourFileSelector.showSaveDialog(null);
                ourSrtFile =  ourFileSelector.getSelectedFile();
                srtPath = ourSrtFile.getAbsolutePath();
                Worker p = new Worker(srtPath, table);
                p.execute();
            }
        };

        Action saveAction = new AbstractAction("Save", saveIcon) {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        };
        Action newAction = new AbstractAction("New", newIcon) {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("New File");
            }
        };
    jMenu1 = new JMenu("File");
    jMenu2 = new JMenu("Video");
    jMenu3 = new JMenu("Subtitle");
    itemNewSrt = new JMenuItem(newAction);
    jMenu1.add(itemNewSrt);
    itemSavefile = new JMenuItem(saveAction);
    jMenu1.add(itemSavefile);
    jMenuBar1 = new JMenuBar();
    jMenuBar1.setBorder(etch);
    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);
    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);
    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);
    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu3);
    ourFileSelector = new JFileChooser();

    Obutton = new JButton[numberOfButton];
    etch = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder();
    //starting and ending time
    enterText = new JTextField();
    enterText.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,100));
    startTime = new JTextField();
    startTime.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 20));
    startTimeingLable = new JLabel("Starting Time");
    endTimeingLabel = new JLabel("Ending Time");
    endTime = new JTextField();
    endTime.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 20));
    //end of start and ending time filed

        toolBar = new JToolBar();
        toolBar.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY, 1));
        toolBar.add(newAction);
        toolBar.add(saveAction);


        JPanel toolBarPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        toolBarPane.add(toolBar,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel timing = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING));
        timing.add(startTimeingLable);
        timing.add(startTime);
        timing.add(endTimeingLabel);
        timing.add(endTime);
        timing.add(laList);

        empty = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30, 5, 5, 5);
        Boveld = BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED);
        Campound = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(empty,Boveld);


        JPanel textFiled = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        textFiled.add(timing);
        textFiled.add(enterText,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        textFiled.setBorder(Campound);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(textFiled, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(toolBarPane,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);





       toolBar.add(openAction);
       itemOpenVideo = new JMenuItem(openAction);
       jMenu1.add(itemOpenVideo);
       //itemOpenVideo.addActionListener(new MenuBarMethod());

    }


     class Worker extends SwingWorker<DefaultTableModel, Void> {
       private final String srtPath;
       private final JTable table;
       DefaultTableModel model;
        public Worker(String srtPath, JTable table) {
                this.srtPath = srtPath;
                this.table = table;
             }


     @Override
      protected DefaultTableModel doInBackground() {
     model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
    ArrayList<String> ends = ReadFile.getFileEndingTime(srtPath);
    ArrayList<String> starts = ReadFile.getFileStartingTime(srtPath);
    ArrayList<String> subs = ReadFile.readSubtitles(srtPath);
    ArrayList<String> lins = ReadFile.ArraylineLengths(srtPath);
    for (int i = 0; i < ReadFile.maxLine(srtPath); i++) {
        model.addRow(new Object[] {lins.get(i), starts.get(i), ends.get(i), subs.get(i)});
    }
    return model;
}
    @Override
     protected void done() {
    table.setModel(model);
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
    TableColumn columnA = table.getColumn("#");
    columnA.setMinWidth(10);
    columnA.setMaxWidth(40);
    TableColumn columnB= table.getColumn("Start");
    columnB.setMinWidth(80);
    columnB.setMaxWidth(90);
    TableColumn columnC= table.getColumn("End");
    columnC.setMinWidth(80);
    columnC.setMaxWidth(90);
}
}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from mixing heavy and light weight components without taking special care of letting them work well together. The easiest and best solution: don't mix heavy-weight and light-weight components together. So avoid using Canvas and instead use the Swing equivalent, the JPanel.

---

**Edit**
If you absolutely need to mix heavy and light weight components, then you need to resolve the issue of getting your pop-up menus to appear over the heavy weight Canvas component. Consider:

```
JPopupMenu.setDefaultLightWeightPopupEnabled(false); 
ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);
```

Comment: i will have issue with this line mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(c));

Comment: and in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777279/adding-a-video-player-to-a-jpanel-in-java-using-vlcj the answer was to change the panel to Canvas

Comment: @jackpeton: yikes, hoisted by my own petard! That question you've linked to was answered in 2012 by ***me***.

Comment: hhhh ok but why this issue is happening can you help me with that plz it is important

Comment: i set this information inside constructor JPopupMenu.setDefaultLightWeightPopupEnabled(false); 
ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false); nothing changed